# php regex replace from array and square brackets

Tags: php, regex, arrays, key

I want to find and replace only words which are in array keys. I try to do this with regex but only with partial succes.

For example:

```
$str = '[something][userName][userEmail][something]';

$user =  array(
    'id' => (string) '2',
    'userName' => (string) 'super user',
    'userEmail' => (string) 'superuser@some.domain',
);

// get the keys.
$keys = array_keys($user);

// get the values.
$values = array_values($user);

// surround each key in word boundary and regex delimiter
// also escape any regex metachar in the key
foreach($keys as &$key) {
    $key = '/\b'.preg_quote($key).'\b/';
}

// do the replacement using preg_replace                
echo preg_replace($keys,$values,$str);
```

This code produces:

[something][super user][superuser@some.domain][something]

What I want to do to get rid the square brackets surrounding the 'super user' and 'superuser@some.domain' but not those surrounding [something] (at the start and finish of the string)

Please help. Regards

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just add square brackets to replace pattern?

```
    $str = '[something][userName][userEmail][something]';

    /* ... */
foreach($keys as &$key) {
       $keyWithSquareBrackets = '[' . $key . ']';
       $key = '/\b'.preg_quote($keyWithSquareBrackets).'\b/';
}

// do the replacement using preg_replace                
echo preg_replace($keys,$values,$str);
```